# first commit in branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration

Whith command

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

I get first commit in project

```
37a8bdc19ce1fd41ebfa1611621da3b30e92ff03
```

With this two I get the same output:

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 master
git rev-list --max-parents=0 branch1
```

How I can get the first commit in branch named "branch1"?

Comment: That *is* the first commit in `branch1`. It's the first commit in *every* branch. (Perhaps what you want is "a commit that exists *only* in branch `branch1`" or "a commit that exists in `branch1` but not also in `master`", and then to do something with the order of such commits.)

Comment: (unless orphan branches were created, but it's a non-standard occurrence) but as @torek said, the same commit is *expected* here.

Comment: Reading past that confusion, can we safely guess your question should be phrased "How to find the first commit in branch X *which is original to X*?" ?

Answer (score 0):

Approach: list all commits that are "new" in the branch compared to master and pick the first one:

```
git log --no-merges --reverse --format='%H' master..branch | head -n1
```

or

```
git rev-list --no-merges --reverse origin/LIVE..origin/UAT | head -n1
```